# Pipe partial line selection through external command in Vim

Tags: vim, base64

I know I can use `:!` with a visual selection to pipe selected *lines* through an external command, but is there a way to do the same for a single word on a line? I need to base64 encode tokens in a config file and I'm having trouble and the entire line is sent to `base64`. If I move the word to its own line, I finish up with a trailing `\n` character encoded in the base64 string. I know there's a plugin specifically for this, but in general is it possible to pipe units of the buffer smaller than entire lines via an external program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Ex commands* (`:!` is one of them) are all line-based, because the *ex editor* on which this mode is based was line-based.

If you need filtering of parts of lines often, I would indeed recommend to use one of the plugins. @romainl's answer outlines the (tedious) steps if you want to do this manually - plugins can greatly simplify that:

- With the venerable [vis.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195), you can use `:B !base64`
- The [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) plugin formerly had `]Y` / `[Y` mappings to encode / decode Base64 directly (implemented in Vimscript)
- [express.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-express) defines a `g=` operator, and will then query for an expression to apply to it. You can use `!base64` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not know about vis.vim. Using that with success. Will also evaluate express.vim.

Comment: Settled on express. vis was appending a newline to the content and messing up the expected base64 result.

Answer (score 4):

Ex commands (everything that starts with `:`) work on lines and there's nothing you can do about that.

Filtering "non-lines" is more involved. You need to:

1. yank the selection,
2. escape it if necessary,
3. run your filter with that selection in a subshell,
4. clean up the output if necessary,
5. replace the selection with the output of the filter.

In a nutshell:

```
c<C-r>=system('echo "<C-r>"" | base64 | tr -d "\n"')<CR>
```

which is obviously a lot more work than for filtering lines. Map it to something easier.

Comment: Thanks, helpful answer. The plugins linked in the other answer look good, so giving that one the tick :)

Comment: No problem, I'm not really a plugin expert.

Comment: You can run from command line with:  :s,\%#\w*,\=system('echo ""<C-r>"" | base64 | tr -d ""\n"" '),c   ie. :s/<cursor>LHS/$(RHS)/confirm